# Modifying PHP Bulletproof to handle non image uploads

Tags: php, bulletproof

I use [Bulletproof](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof) to handle image uploads in PHP and it is awesome. I am now working with a multipart form which will send images as well as other file types (specifically .pdf, .doc and .docx). I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864886/can-bulletproof-php-upload-pdf-and-word-files) where the author of [Bulletproof](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof) class mentioned that it would take 5 mins to modify the class to handle other file types. I have tried changing the mime types defined in the class as well as manually defining them in my code while invoking the class but I seem to be missing something. Has anyone had any luck with this before?
I am posting this as a new question because I can't comment on other questions yet and have not found the answer to this on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, somehow didn't see it despite subscribing to the <kbd>bulletproof</kbd> tag.

So, to modify the class and enable it to upload a file type you want, then you have to modify a couple of lines.

First, there is a compiled list of acceptable MimeTypes that are stored in [`$imageMimes](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/blob/master/src/bulletproof.php#L72-L77)` variable. In this file you have to add MimeType of the file you want to upload: ex: for PDF it would be `application/pdf`

Then you have to remove lines that check the images width/height in pixels or MimeType that expects it to be an image  from [this](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/blob/master/src/bulletproof.php#L305-L311), [this](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/blob/master/src/bulletproof.php#L315-L316), [this](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/blob/master/src/bulletproof.php#L350-L351) and [this](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/blob/master/src/bulletproof.php#L331-L341) line.

That will get rid of the function that checks image dimension or mime from being called. So, you can't use `$image->height`, `$image->width` or `$image->mime`  anywhere.

To recap, this would be you should do it:

```
class BF extends \Bulletproof {

   protected $imageMimes = [..... , 'application/pdf']; 

   public function upload () {
     // make the suggested edits here
   }
}
```

And when you have to upload, you should pass the mime types you want to set via the `setMime()` function as:

```
$bf = new \BF($_FILES);
$bf->setMime(['application/pdf']);
if($bf['pictures']){

  echo $bf->upload() ? '1' : '0'; 
}
```

I'm working on a version that does not force you to manually edit the file to make similar changes. But for now, follow my example and understand the only constraints to upload anyfile with Bulletproof lies on the functions that check/get image height, width or MimeType.

If you remove the MimeType verifications from inside the `upload(){}`method then know you have to add a code to check if the type you set is the same as the uploaded one.